# htaccess string replace in the request uri so new domain & sub domains work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Pretty simple here, I have 6 websites and 1 main site

olddomain.com

sub1.olddomain.com

sub2.olddomain.com

etc.

I need to change the olddomain.com to newdomain.com and any incoming queries for example:

Root level should work like

sub2.olddomain.com = sub2.newdomain.com

But also need this to work

sub2.olddomain.com/contact/us = sub2.newdomain.com/contact/us

I almost need to string replace olddomain.com to newdomain.com in the requesting URL in the htaccess so as to get all subdomains as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this generic redirect rule in site root .htaccess of `olddomain`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!